# Boundary change in double integral: $\int_t^T \left( \int_t^u r(s)ds \right)du = \frac{1}{T}\int_t^T (T-s)r(s)ds$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have following problem. I have been reading an article on pricing Asian options and I have found one article directly concerning my topic. However, it is horribly written and I am trying to deconstruct it.

Source: http://www.math.zju.edu.cn/amjcu/B/200602/02.pdf
(calculation leading to (3.10)

I have trouble understanding, why the authors could write following:

$\int_t^T \left( \int_t^u r(s)ds \right)du =  \frac{1}{T}\int_t^T (T-s)r(s)ds$

Obviously, the equation is ture for any non time dependent $r$, but can it be generalised for any function $r(s)$?

Could you please show me or delegate me to relevant theorem that can help me explain this?

Thank you very much for your help!
J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One may see an integration by parts here,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_t^T \left( \int_t^u r(s)ds \right)du &=\left[ \frac{(u-T)}{T}\left(\int_t^u r(s)ds\right)\right]_t^T-\frac1T\int_t^T(u-T)r(u)\:dt
\\\\&=\color{red}{0}+\frac1T\int_t^T(T-u)r(u)\:dt
\end{align}
$$ as announced.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really did not see it there.

Comment: @Jakub Kubis You are welcome.